# Eclipse CDT file template include style

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

In `Preferences -> C/C++ -> Code Style -> Code templates`, the "Default C++ source template" looks like this:

```
${filecomment}
${includes}

${namespace_begin}

${declarations}

${namespace_end}
```

If I create a new C++ class `Foo` using this template, the source file looks like this:

```
/*
 * Copyright etc.
 */

#include <foo.h>

Foo::Foo()
{
}
```

This guarantees that the file can not be successfully compiled, because foo.h (in the current directory) is not found when `#include <foo.h>` is used. The include line should be `#include "foo.h"`.

For the header, the ${includes} variable contains the headers of the base classes. For the c++ file, it contains its own header. It is constructed by Eclipse.

Is it possible to change the #include <> style to #include "" ? I don't want to use `-I.` just to work around this inconvenience.

Comment: "I don't want to use a solution, just a workaround" :p

Comment: You could try replacing `${includes}` with `#include "${file_base}.h"`

Comment: Its weird because my copy of eclipse does it with `""` to begin with. Maybe update your eclipse?

Comment: I can't write a proper answer now, but do you have the directory containing foo.h in your include directories as determined by the scanner? CDT uses <> if you have the directory in your includes and "" if your project does not.

Comment: @JonahGraham. Thanks. The directory in which the source and the header are located is not in the "Include directories" list under "C++ General / Paths and Symbols". Its grandparent is, however. The same grandparent is present in a -I compiler switch.

Comment: I have another use case: I need to hard code manually include in each C source file. I have added this line in XML file: `#include &lt;common/types.h&gt;`.
`#include "common/types.h";` works too.